# How do I fill in values for columns based on matching few other column's row values in R

Tags: r

Data looks like below.

```
 time <- c('Nov 1st 2014, 17:36:50.000','Nov 1st 2014, 17:36:50.000',
          'Nov 1st 2014, 17:36:50.000','Nov 1st 2014, 17:36:50.000', 'Nov 1st 2014, 17:37:50.000','Nov 1st 2014, 17:37:50.000','Nov 1st 2014, 17:37:50.000')
A <- c('20.79','NA','NA','NA','21.8','NA','NA')  
B <- c('NA','97.017','94.321','85.014','NA','87.1','67.1')
C <- c('NA','C1','C2','C3','NA','C1','C2')
D <- c('L1','L1','L1','L1','L2','L2','L2')
C1 <- c('NA','NA','NA','NA','NA','NA','NA')
C2 <- c('NA','NA','NA','NA','NA','NA','NA')
C3 <- c('NA','NA','NA','NA','NA','NA','NA')
df <- data.frame(time,A,B,C,D,C1,C2,C3)
```

I need output in the below format.

```
#   time                           A     B  C    D        C1     C2      C3
# 1 Nov 1st 2014, 17:36:50.000  20.79    NA NA   L1       97.02  94.321  85.014
    Nov 1st 2014, 17:37:50.000  21.8     NA NA   L2       87.1   67.1   47.3
```

How do I get the data in the above format in just one row as columns "time" and "D"  are same for all the rows?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the example instead of images as we can't copy fro images to test

Comment: Updated the code to test. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Step-by-step approach

If I understand correctly, OP's dataset actually consists of two intermixed datasets:

```
df
```

> ```
>                         time     A      B  C  D C1 C2 C3
> 1 Nov 1st 2014, 17:36:50.000 20.79     NA NA L1 NA NA NA
> 2 Nov 1st 2014, 17:36:50.000    NA 97.017 C1 L1 NA NA NA
> 3 Nov 1st 2014, 17:36:50.000    NA 94.321 C2 L1 NA NA NA
> 4 Nov 1st 2014, 17:36:50.000    NA 85.014 C3 L1 NA NA NA
> 5 Nov 1st 2014, 17:37:50.000  21.8     NA NA L2 NA NA NA
> 6 Nov 1st 2014, 17:37:50.000    NA   87.1 C1 L2 NA NA NA
> 7 Nov 1st 2014, 17:37:50.000    NA   67.1 C2 L2 NA NA NA
> ```

which need to be separated:

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- setDT(df)[A != "NA", .(time, A, D)]
df1
```

> ```
>                          time     A  D
> 1: Nov 1st 2014, 17:36:50.000 20.79 L1
> 2: Nov 1st 2014, 17:37:50.000  21.8 L2
> ```

and

```
df2 <- df[A == "NA", .(time, B, C, D)]
df2
```

> ```
>                          time      B  C  D
> 1: Nov 1st 2014, 17:36:50.000 97.017 C1 L1
> 2: Nov 1st 2014, 17:36:50.000 94.321 C2 L1
> 3: Nov 1st 2014, 17:36:50.000 85.014 C3 L1
> 4: Nov 1st 2014, 17:37:50.000   87.1 C1 L2
> 5: Nov 1st 2014, 17:37:50.000   67.1 C2 L2
> ```

The key columns which identify unique subsets of rows are `time` and `D`. Columns `C1`, `C2`, and `C3` are dropped as they will be created in the next step.

The second dataset is to be reshaped from long to wide format:

```
wide <- dcast(df2, time + D ~ C, value.var = "B")
wide
```

> ```
>                          time  D     C1     C2     C3
> 1: Nov 1st 2014, 17:36:50.000 L1 97.017 94.321 85.014
> 2: Nov 1st 2014, 17:37:50.000 L2   87.1   67.1   <NA>
> ```

Now both partial results can be joined together:

```
df1[wide, on = .(time, D)]
```

> ```
>                          time     A  D     C1     C2     C3
> 1: Nov 1st 2014, 17:36:50.000 20.79 L1 97.017 94.321 85.014
> 2: Nov 1st 2014, 17:37:50.000  21.8 L2   87.1   67.1   <NA>
> ```

Note that columns `B` and `C` have been dropped from the result as they convey no information.

#### Compact code

This steps above can be combined into fewer statements:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, (paste0("C", 1:3)) := NULL]
df[A != "NA"][dcast(df[C != "NA"], time + D ~ C, value.var = "B"), on = .(time, D)]
```

> ```
>                          time     A  B  C  D     C1     C2     C3
> 1: Nov 1st 2014, 17:36:50.000 20.79 NA NA L1 97.017 94.321 85.014
> 2: Nov 1st 2014, 17:37:50.000  21.8 NA NA L2   87.1   67.1   <NA>
> ```

#### Data

as provided by the OP with NA values given as strings

```
time <- c('Nov 1st 2014, 17:36:50.000','Nov 1st 2014, 17:36:50.000',
          'Nov 1st 2014, 17:36:50.000','Nov 1st 2014, 17:36:50.000', 'Nov 1st 2014, 17:37:50.000','Nov 1st 2014, 17:37:50.000','Nov 1st 2014, 17:37:50.000')
A <- c('20.79','NA','NA','NA','21.8','NA','NA')  
B <- c('NA','97.017','94.321','85.014','NA','87.1','67.1')
C <- c('NA','C1','C2','C3','NA','C1','C2')
D <- c('L1','L1','L1','L1','L2','L2','L2')
C1 <- c('NA','NA','NA','NA','NA','NA','NA')
C2 <- c('NA','NA','NA','NA','NA','NA','NA')
C3 <- c('NA','NA','NA','NA','NA','NA','NA')
df <- data.frame(time,A,B,C,D,C1,C2,C3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `dplyr::gather()` to re-shape B into C1, C2, C3, and then `dplyr::join()` it with the other columns, assuming a unique date/time.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  select(time, A, B, C, D) %>%
  filter(!is.na(A)) %>%
  left_join(
    df %>%
      select(time, C, B, D) %>%
      spread(C, B) %>%
      select(-`<NA>`),
    by = c("time", "D")
  )

#                         time     A  B    C  D     C1     C2     C3
# 1 Nov 1st 2014, 17:36:50.000 20.79 NA <NA> L1 97.017 94.321 85.014
# 2 Nov 1st 2014, 17:37:50.000 21.80 NA <NA> L2 87.100 67.100 47.300
```

## data

```
df <- read.table(text = "time A B C D C1 C2 C3
1 'Nov 1st 2014, 17:36:50.000' 20.79 NA NA L1 NA NA NA
2 'Nov 1st 2014, 17:36:50.000' NA 97.017 C1 L1 NA NA NA
3 'Nov 1st 2014, 17:36:50.000' NA 94.321 C2 L1 NA NA NA
4 'Nov 1st 2014, 17:36:50.000' NA 85.014 C3 L1 NA NA NA
5 'Nov 1st 2014, 17:37:50.000' 21.8 NA NA L2 NA NA NA
6 'Nov 1st 2014, 17:37:50.000' NA 87.1 C1 L2 NA NA NA
7 'Nov 1st 2014, 17:37:50.000' NA 67.1 C2 L2 NA NA NA
8 'Nov 1st 2014, 17:37:50.000' NA 47.3 C3 L2 NA NA NA",
                 header = T,
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The date/time here is not unique. Updated the dataset above.

Comment: It should still work, as long as the date/time is unique for each set of 4 rows.

Comment: Not every date/time has set of 4 rows

Comment: Please provide a full/complete reproducible example so I know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Paul, I believe you are pretty close. Just consider both `time` and `D` as key columns.